# Trouble getting div to display at the very top of the screen

Tags: html, css

I am trying a simple practice problem to learn CSS, I am having trouble trying to have a div display at the very top of the screen. As you can see with the background-color, it is not touching the top, yet if you look at the image below it you see that adding a border fixes the issue for some reason.

[No border, with space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFhvn.png)
[With border, no space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRYul.png)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div#wrap {
  background-color: #55ccff;
  width: 60%;
  min-width: 600px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <h1>Stuff</h1>
  <p>
    Stuff
  </p>
  <ul>
    <li>Stuff here</li>
  </ul>

  <p class="copyright">
    Stuff
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<h1>` element also has a margin that is causing the gap you see. You can remove it like you did on the body element.

```css
body, h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

div#wrap {
  background-color: #55ccff;
  width: 60%;
  min-width: 600px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <h1>Stuff</h1>
  <p>
    Stuff
  </p>
  <ul>
    <li>Stuff here</li>
  </ul>

  <p class="copyright">
    Stuff
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, something so simple. I'll accept your answer as soon as it allows me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser gives default styles to most elements. The best thing to do when starting a new project is to put "resets" at the beginning of the css file. This cancels out the default styles.

A standard reset that alot of people use is Erics reset found [here](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). place this code at the top of your css file and you will be good to go.

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding 'overflow: auto;' to your #wrap declaration. The default browser margin on the heading is causing the issue.